# Pinless moisture meters

Tags: capacitance, meter, humidity

I have read that most pinless moisture meters are based on the principle of capacitance.  I know that when the material loses water, the dielectric constant of the material decreases and the capacitance of the material goes down as well, altering the moisture content read on screen.  However, many moisture meter websites say they use an RF field to take moisture measurements.  My question is, how does the RF field work with the capacitor to detect moisture?  To me, it seems like they are two separate technologies.  (What does the RF signal do?  How does it help to measure moisture?)

[image: Moisture meter (pinless)]

https://www.lowes.com/pd/General-Tools-Instruments-Digital-Test-Meter/50284821

Answer (score 0):

To measure the capacity the voltage on the sensor probe is modulated (AC). The moisture level then has an effect on the probe's AC characteristic, e.g. the resonant frequency of the probe.

On the other hand, the medium you want to measure will see a RF field being induced (the probe is isolated from the medium).

"RF" and "AC" corresponds to the same thing here: AC in the antenna (probe) will cause RF in the medium.

Comment: So, the frequency of the AC is what indicates a change in moisture?  Do you know if the frequency increases or decreases as a piece of wood gains moisture?

Is the RF field that is produced the electric field from the capacitor that is oscillating at a rate in the range of RF?

Is the AC and RF the same frequency?